# Create login/signup page before routing to main page in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, user-accounts, atmosphere.js

I have a global route that uses layout.html which specifies the header.html. 
I would like to know how to:

1) have a main landing page for login/sign up with the proper formatting, without the header. (Im using UserAccounts from Atmosphere but formatting is different, not sure why). Also the header in layout.js cannot be removed.

2) Upon login/sign in, it should go to main page.

Can someone advise how ?

```
Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'layout', //This is where header is specified globally
      waitOn: function() { 
        return [Meteor.subscribe('notifications')]
      }
    });

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'auth'
}); //added this new line

Router.route('/posts', {
  name: 'home',
  controller: NewPostsController
});

var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'postPage'});
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'postSubmit'});
```

**This is the layout.html defined globally.**

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    {{> header}}
    {{> errors}}

    <div id="main">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Update after @Chase's suggestion. 
- It works on the routing and header is gone. 
- Formatting is different from the website though.

What I have is shown below while its supposed to look like
http://useraccounts.meteor.com/
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this set up you won't need to set the layout with header for every route.

The User Accounts package has a Iron Router plugin to ensure the user is signed in that I use ([more info](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#content-protection)). I also configure routes supplied by the User Accounts package ([more info](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#routing)) so I can directly route to a User Accounts sign up page.

**Javascript**

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout' //main layout with header
});

//Iron router plugin to ensure user is signed in
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('ensureSignedIn', {
    template: 'atTemplate', //template shown if user is not signed in
    layoutTemplate: 'atLayout' //template for login, registration, etc
});

//Don't require user to be logged in for these routes
Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn', {
    except: ['login', 'register']
});

//Configure route for login
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login',
    template: 'atTemplate',
    layoutTemplate: 'atLayout',
    redirect: '/'
});

//Configure route for registration
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
    name: 'register',
    path: '/register',
    template: 'atTemplate',
    layoutTemplate: 'atLayout',
    redirect: '/'
});

//Home page to show once logged in
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    action: function(){
        this.render('home');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="layout">
    <div class="container">
        {{> header}}
        {{> errors}}

        <div id="main">
            {{> yield}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="atLayout">
    <div class="at-container">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="atTemplate">
    {{> atForm}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chase. I cant seem to achieve the same formatting as displayed on the site. Do you know why? I attached the pic above.

Comment: What UserAccounts style package are you using?

Comment: I'm using semantic-ui. I tried with styleless, the m and the p...all ends up same. I tried deleting all my CSS...doesn't work too.

Comment: hmm... not sure what the issue could be without digging into your code. You may be better off posting this issue as a separate question.

Comment: its done. Link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862115/how-do-i-get-the-built-in-formatting-for-useraccounts-meteor-to-work

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 diferents layouts templates with different setup.

**Javascript**

```
Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'adminLayout', //layout without header
   });

Router.route('/', { //main page, different layout
     layout:layout,
     name: 'auth'
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="adminLayout">
  <div class="container">
    {{> errors}}
    <div id="main">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

With this you will have diferents layouts, to diferentes routes.

Comment: Hi Ethaan, just to clarify. Doesnt the auth route you wrote use the same adminLayout as the layout template?

Comment: it was just an example, let me fix it.

Comment: and you have a `Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'autht', //layout without header
   });` ?

Comment: Sorry ignore my previous message. realised  both layout and name fields has to be filled with 'input' with the '' or "". Please continue with your answer. Sounds like it will work! But does it mean if i want the header to appear...I have to fill it as `layout: 'adminLayout_with_header'`in every route where the header should appear?

Comment: well yes, if you are using the yield helper and want to use different "masters" layouts you should specify wich route will use wich layout

Comment: I managed to follow Chase's recommendation. But the formatting is off