# How do I get the built in formatting for UserAccounts Meteor to work?

Tags: javascript, meteor, user-accounts, meteor-accounts, atmosphere.js

I have included the UserAccounts (Semantic UI) package with the meteor app.

On inserting the routes and the {{> atForm}}, this is how my front page looks.

[image: Front page screenshot]

Which is very different from the examples shown here: [**UserAccount Page**](http://useraccounts.meteor.com/)

**Steps taken:**

- Deleted the entire Css
- Deleted and reinstalled other packages like Unstyled or boostrap

But nothing works. Formatting is still the one in the picture. 
Can someone please help or provide advice? 
Let me know which codes you need to review, I'll post them on request as soon as Im able to.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give a bit more specific information on whats not working? Its displaying the form so thats working ;-). Also do you have any errors in your js console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `useraccounts:semantic-ui` does not add any style sheets to your app: please see the [Bring Your Own Semantic-UI](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/semantic-ui#bring-your-own-semantic-ui) section in the docs.

At the moment there are official packages to add SUI style sheets:

- [semantic:ui-css](https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui-css): full compiled CSS version
- [semantic:ui](https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui): customizable LESS version (some work is still in progress